# Cordova Camera - Can't access library

Tags: android, cordova, camera, ionic-framework

I try to use the Cordova Camera plugin in Ionic context (on Android) to take a picture using camera or pick a picture from the library.

I can take a picture but it seems that the picture is not resized using my options.

However, I can't open the photo library as it always opens the camera.

Here is my code :

```
$scope.takePicture = function()
  {
     var options = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: false,
      targetWidth: 250,
      targetHeight: 350,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      correctOrientation: true,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    };

    navigator.camera.getPicture(
      function(imageURI) {
         $scope.exercise.image = imageURI;
      }, 
      function(err) {
        // error
      },
      options);
  };

  $scope.browsePicture = function()
  {
    var options = {
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      allowEdit: false,
      targetWidth: 250,
      targetHeight: 350,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      correctOrientation: true
    };

    navigator.camera.getPicture(
      function(imageURI) {
         $scope.exercise.image = imageURI;
      }, 
      function(err) {
        // error
      },
      options);
  };
```

I have another method which deletes my image. But when I use it (via a button), it also opens the camera.

```
  $scope.deletePicture = function()
  {
    $scope.exercise.image = null;
  };
```

And, if I click on my html img tag, it also opens the camera. However, I haven't attach any method on the tag.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: can you please share html side code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)` to work for taking a picture or from a library.Here am posting a sample code for camera which worked for me 
In your controller write the camera code as

```
         $scope.userPic = function(){
            console.log("userPic function got called");
            $ionicPopup.show({
              template: '<p>Take picture or use from library</p>',
              title: 'Choose',
              buttons: [
                {
                  text: '<b>Camera</b>',
                  onTap: function(e) {
                    return "camera";
                  }
                },
                {
                  text: '<b>Library</b>',
                  type: 'button-positive',
                  onTap: function(e) {
                    return "library";
                  }
                },
              ]
            }).then(function(resp) {
              $scope.takePicture(resp);
              console.log('resp', resp);
            });
        }

        $scope.takePicture = function(resp){
            console.log("takePicture function got called");
            console.log(resp);
            var source;
            if (resp == "camera") {
              source = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
            }else{
              source = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
            };
            var options = {
              quality : 75,
              destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
              sourceType : source,
              allowEdit : true,
              encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
              targetWidth: 300,
              targetHeight: 300,
              popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
              saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            };
             $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
                console.log(imageData);
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                // error
            });
             }
```

In your HTML write the camera button code as

```
    <button class="button button-bar button-balanced" ng-click="userPic()">
      Camera
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I implemented it through code :

```
var getPicture = function(pictureType)
  {
    var source;

    if (pictureType == "camera") {
      source = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
    }else{
      source = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
    };

    var options = {
      quality : 75,
      destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType : source,
      allowEdit : true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 300,
      targetHeight: 300,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };

     $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
        $scope.exercise.image = imageURI;
    }, function(err) {
        alert(err);
        // error
    });
  };

  $scope.takePicture = function()
  {

    getPicture('camera');


     /*var options = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: false,
      targetWidth: 250,
      targetHeight: 350,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      correctOrientation: true,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI){
      $scope.exercise.image = imageURI;
    }, 
    function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        // error
    });*/

    /*navigator.camera.getPicture(
      function(imageURI) {
         $scope.exercise.image = imageURI;
      }, 
      function(err) {
        // error
      },
      options);*/
  };

  $scope.browsePicture = function()
  {
    getPicture('browse');


    /*var options = {
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      allowEdit: false,
      targetWidth: 250,
      targetHeight: 350,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      correctOrientation: true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI){
      $scope.exercise.image = imageURI;
    }, 
    function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        // error
    });*/

    /*navigator.camera.getPicture(
      function(imageURI) {
         $scope.exercise.image = imageURI;
      }, 
      function(err) {
        // error
      },
      options);*/
  };
```

This doesn't work, in both cases, it's always my camera who open.

EDIT : Here is my HTML :

```
    <div class="row" ng-hide="exercise.image">
      <div class="col"><button class="button button-clear button-calm button-block" ng-click="takePicture()">Take Picture</button></div>
      <div class="col"><button class="button button-clear button-balanced button-block" ng-click="browsePicture()">Browse Pictures</button></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: check the value of pictureType what it is coming.

Comment: pictureType is 'camera' or 'browse'.

Comment: your code is working perfectly for me I just tested it on my mobile, It is opening camera & library as separately

Comment: Ok that's weird. What is your phone and Android Version ? Mine is Motorola MotoG 4G and Android 5.1

Comment: OK now that i changed the way of display buttons, the library is working. Seems that 2 buttons side by side was causing the issue.